# Will a looping batch eat up resources?

Tags: loops, batch-file

Hi i wrote a very simple batch that looks for files in a folder and if it doesnt find any, it looks again, but if it finds files, it sends them to another location. This batch loops infinitely. Will this eat up resources until the computer crashes? Its using `If Exists` then a `MOVE`. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - but it will eat CPU power.

The usual approach to this problem is installing a `timeout` (the `timeout` command) which effectively suspends the batch for a user-selectable number of seconds.

Whether it is usable in your situation, only you can decide.

Answer (score 0):

Or switch to PowerShell and get NTFS to do the hard work:

```
[System.IO.FileSystemWatcher]             $objWatcher = $null;
[System.Management.Automation.PSEventJob] $objEvent   = $null;

#
# Define code for handling new files.
#
[scriptblock] $objActionCreated  = { Write-Host -Object ( 'File created; full path is "{0}" and file name is "{1}".' -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath, $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name ); }

#
# Create file system watcher and register.
#
try {
    $objWatcher              = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileSystemWatcher;
    $objWatcher.Path         = 'c:\temp';
    $objWatcher.NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName';
    $objEvent                = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $objWatcher -EventName 'Created' -Action $objActionCreated;
    } #try
catch [System.Exception] {
    } #catch
```